# I have a .fsx f# script file in Visual Studio, and i want to build an exe that executes it, how should i proceed?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, f#, exe, f#-scripting

I'm working with visual studio 2015.
I undestood that I have to create a console application project, then I added the scripts. Now i don't understand what I have to do.

my main is just 4 lines of code

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0
```

and i suppose i have to call the .fsx files in some way, but how?
Maybe I have to edit the AssemblyInfo.fs file?
Thanks, and sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: Scripts don't get compiled. They're scripts. To compile the program, put it in an `.fs` file, then build the project.

Comment: [Getting Started with F# in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-visual-studio). Whatever is in the fsx files place them into Program.fs (that has your main()) or any other .fs file above your Program.fs. Make sure to wrap script related directives like `#r` or `#load` with `#if INTERACTIVE #endif`.